# Alternate reduction from 3SAT to 4SAT?

Tags: reductions, satisfiability

It seems that the standard reduction method you see online from 3SAT to 4SAT is that we let $\phi = (a \lor b \lor c)$ be a 3SAT clause, and so there is an assignment that satisfies $\phi$ iff $\phi' = (a \lor b \lor c \lor z) \land (a \lor b \lor c \lor \neg z)$ is also satisfiable.

Is it just as valid to say that $(a \lor b \lor c)$ is satisfiable iff $(a \lor b \lor c \lor c)$ is satisfiable? This seems like a much simple solution..

Comment: $(a \vee b \vee c \vee c)$ is not a 4SAT clause, but a 3SAT clause. It has three (unique) variables.

Comment: fair enough, that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact definition of $k$-SAT that's being used.  If $k$-SAT is defined to have clauses of length *at most* $k$, your reduction is perfect; if it's defined to have clauses with *exactly* four *distinct* literals, then you're out of luck.

Comment: If OP wants to use the _at most_ $k$-SAT definition, he doesn't need a reduction at all since 3SAT is _at most_ 4SAT by definition

Answer (score 0):

The SAT order of operations would reduce the variables in a clause to unique literals before evaluating the formula.  However, I couldn't find a reference to support this claim.